# postgres without installation on Windows- Fatal error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted

Tags: pgadmin

Trying to run pgAdmin after setting up postgres without installation like described [here][1]

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26441939/15307393 I am getting the fatal error `The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted`. Starting postgres server with `pgctl` and connect with `psql` is working.

Do I have to start the pgAdmin server manually somehow?

Comment: The Postgres Windows service is completely independent of the "pgAdmin server". Your pgAdmin installation isn't working, Postgres is fine if you can connect via psql.

Comment: Any suggestions? I downloaded the files provided in the linked answer (that is written by you too ;) )

Comment: The Postgres installation (that my answer describes) has nothing to do with pgAdmin. Sorry, I don't use pgAdmin so I don't know what went wrong during the pgAdmin installation (or non-installation). Maybe the pgAdmin included in the ZIP file doesn't work without installation. Did you try to delete that and download pgAdmin directly from https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: I deleted and installed from pgadmin.org to C:/ drive like recommend by the installer (real installation). Also tried on another Windows machine and another version of pgAdmin. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error